# comparing two strings for percentage match

Tags: php

I am trying to compare a user submitted string to a string of a database record and see how close they are in terms of %

i have found this rather interesting code which looks like a good solution

```
Function Compare(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As Double
Dim count As Integer = If(str1.Length > str2.Length, str1.Length, str2.Length)
Dim hits As Integer = 0
Dim i, j As Integer : i = 0 : j = 0
For i = 0 To str1.Length - 1
If str1.Chars(i) = " " Then i += 1 : j = str2.IndexOf(" "c, j) + 1 : hits += 1
While j < str2.Length AndAlso str2.Chars(j) <> " "c
  If str1.Chars(i) = str2.Chars(j) Then
    hits += 1
    j += 1
    Exit While
  Else
    j += 1
  End If
End While
If Not (j < str2.Length AndAlso str2.Chars(j) <> " "c) Then
  j -= 1
End If
Next
Return Math.Round((hits / count), 2)
End Function
```

firstly can anyone tell me what the language is used above, and can anyone help me convert it to php please?

i've tried to convert it but ran in to a bit of trouble early on

```
function compare($str1,$str2) as $double
{
$count = if(strlen($str1) > strlen($str2), strlen($str1) > strlen($str2));
$hits = 0;
$i - 0;
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str1); $i++)
{
    if($str1[$i] == " ")
    {
        $i .= "1";
    }
}
}
```

any help with this would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Where did you find the code? Maybe that would be the first clue? Think it is Visual Basic.

Comment: As a slight aside, have you consider using `int levenshtein ( string $str1 , string $str2 )` to measure the similarity of the strings? Or do you have to use something like above?

Comment: See this and choose your favorite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Comment: it was something i found using a google search, website is codeproject :)... i'm just after something that will give me the most accurate result and a percentage at the end :) im doing a db search and trying to return closest matches thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an option, then, try something like this:

```
$teststr = "This is a test.";
$dbstr = "This was a test.";

$percent = (1 - levenshtein($teststr, $dbstr)/max( strlen($teststr),strlen($dbstr) ) ) * 100;

print "Percent match".$percent."\n";

Percent match: 92.857142857143
```

Far more info at: https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.levenshtein.php